# Does this site offer a notification for obscure topics?

Tags: discussion

I'm new here and am wondering whether I can get email notifications anytime someone tags a question with a particular topic. Obviously I don't want to see everything that comes through with "notation" or "piano", but it might be nice to get a heads up about more obscure topics that interest me, like "clarsach" or "mixolydian".  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can subscribe to a tag. If you hover over a tag, you'll see the `subscribe` option:

[image]

Unfortunately there aren't tags for the two terms that you propose, and they are probably too specific to have their own tag. You could try subscribing to related tags like [modes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modes) and [harp](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harp)?

More information here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags